Integrating "mixed" integrals such as $\int_{10}^\infty x^a\cos(t\log(x))\ \tanh(x/2) \,\mathrm dx$
How do we calculate 'mixed' integrals of the form
$$
\int_{10}^{\infty}x^{a}\cos\left(\,t\log\left(\ x\,\right)\,\right)\tanh\left(x \over 2\right){\rm d}x\ ?,
$$
where $a$ and $t$ are real constants.

What I mean by 'mixed' is one that involves normal functions like power ( $x^{a}$ above ) and both $\sin, \cos, \tan$ as well as $\sinh, \cosh, \tanh$ in product.
I understand how we can do each separately but not this.
Can someone please help ( with above example ) as well as a general technique ?.
Secondly, is there a region ( of the limits ) where we can predict the integral sums to $0$ or say has a periodic nature. For example if it
were simple $\sin$ we know its period.


$1)$ Did you prove it converges? $2)$ Why do you believe it has a closed form?


I did not but if the convergence depends on the constants $a, t$ we can assume their value is such that the integral does converge. 2) I do not but thus the Q.


I see 0 answer but a downvote (not sure why!).. Is this trivial cause i don't see it..

the downvote is probably due to the lack of context. You can't multiply a bunch of functions and expect to find a closed form of the integral

$a, t$ are some constants.. $x$ the variable of integration..

@SineoftheTime its a part of something i am studying.. i don't know what else to say.. i gave idea about the conceptual Q about what i want to do (find an approach to integrate mixed equations).. would it still be bunching together?

are you studying on a book or something?

yes.. self study.. my background is CS.. so newbie here..

$\displaystyle\Re\left(a\right) < -1$ because your integrand becomes $\displaystyle \Re\left[x^{a + t{\rm i}}\cdots\right]$

@FelixMarin $a, t$ are real constants (I updated the Q).. but i am unclear about your comment.. i am a newbie..

What he is saying is that the real part of $a$ (if it is real, that means $a$ itself of course) must be smaller than $-1$, otherwise the integral does not converge for $x\rightarrow \infty$.
Anyway, note that $\cos(t\log x) = \Re x^{\text{i} t}$, so the integral is just something like $\int_c^\infty x^z \tanh(x/2)$, which is representable as a sum of incomplete Gamma functions. Result doesn't look pretty though. Probably $c=0$ with further bounds on $z$ leads to something more neat

$\displaystyle\cos\left(,t\log\left(,x,\right),\right) = \Re\left(,x^{{\rm i}t},\right)$

As the comments pointed out we want a lower bound of $0$ for a nice solution (otherwise the integral most likely does ot have a closed formula). Furthermore then we requiere $a \in (-2,-1)$ for convergence. Let $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z=a+it$. Then we can express  $$\int_{0}^\infty x^a \cos(t \ln(x)) \tanh(x/2) dx= \Re \int_{0}^\infty x^z \tanh(x/2)dx~.$$
The last integral can be transformed with the geometric series. However, to ensure convergence, one must integrate by parts or (even better) use a method for summing divergent series. A straight forward calculation now yields $$\int_{0}^\infty x^a \cos(t \ln(x)) \tanh(x/2) dx= -\Re\left(2 \Gamma(z+1) \eta(z+1)\right)= \Re\left( 2(2^{-z} -1) \Gamma(z+1) \zeta(z+1) \right) ~. $$
($\eta$ and $\zeta$ denote the Dirichlet-$\eta$ and Riemann-$\zeta$ function respectively.)
Form here one can  explicitly write out the real-part or so, but the last result is as strong as it gets.
I try to roughly outline the calculation:
By integration by parts we have (Integrate the $x^z$ differentiate, the $\tanh$ and boundary term is $0$ because $a \in (-2,-1$ )) $$\int_{0}^\infty x^z \tanh(x/2) dx = -2/(z+1) \int_{0}^\infty x^{z+1} \frac{e^x}{(1+e^x)^2} dx~.$$ Now recall that for any $q$ with $|q|<1$ we have $$\frac{1}{(1-q)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k q^{k-1}$$
that is the geometric sum formula I mentioned. Note that for any $x>0$ we have $|-e^{-x}|<1$ so we conclude $$ \int_{0}^\infty x^{z+1} \frac{e^x}{(1+e^x)^2} \frac{(e^{-x})^2}{(e^{-x})^2}dx = \int_{0}^\infty x^{z+1}e^{-x} \frac{1}{(1+e^{-x})^2} dx \\ = \int_{0}^\infty x^{z+1}e^{-x} \sum_{k=1}^\infty k (-e^{-x})^{k-1} =  \int_{0}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty k (-1)^{k-1} x^{z+1} e^{-kx}dx~.$$
Now for the big question: can pull the integral inside the sum??? The answer is NO. unless we modify the sum to ensure convergence, so we apply a method for summing divergent series. (Maybe look up Cesaro or Ramanujan summation for this step.) This means that we will end up with a divergent sum, which we will give a finite value. We are now dealing with $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty  k (-1)^{k-1}  \int_{0}^\infty x^{z+1} e^{-kx}dx$$ now set $kx=u$.Then we have $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty  k (-1)^{k-1}  \int_{0}^\infty x^{z+1} e^{-kx}dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} k^{-z-1} \int_{0}^\infty u^{z+1} e^{-u} du~.$$
Now you can notice two things ,a) the integral does not depeend on $k$, b) the series defines the Dirichlet-$\eta$ function (it is the standart defintion, look that up!) it is importent to point out that the series does not converge in the usual sence for any values of $z$ that would make the integral converge!. Putting everything together we see $$\int_{0}^\infty x^z \tanh(x/2) dx = \frac{-2}{z+1} \left( \int_{0}^\infty u^{z+2}e^{-u} du \right) \left(  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{z+1}} \right) = \frac{-2}{z+1} \Gamma(z+2) \eta(z+1)~. $$
Note that included the $-2$ to fix the sign of the series and now replaced the defining integral of the $\Gamma$ function and series for the $\eta$ function with the short symbols. One can easily proof with integration by parts that $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$. With this we can make one more simplifaication $$\frac{-2}{z+1} \Gamma(z+2) \eta(z+1) = (-2)\Gamma(z+1) \eta(z+1)~.$$ Now we conclude the final equation: $$\int_{0}^\infty x^a \cos(t \ln(x)) \tanh(x/2) dx= \Re \int_{0}^\infty x^z \tanh(x/2)dx = \Re \left( -2)\Gamma(z+1) \eta(z+1) \right) $$
You can use the functional equation for $\eta$ and $\zeta$, but I will stop here!

Thanks. But i am unclear (may be even unsure) about why $a \in (-2,-1)$ is the case. You mean to say for all other values other than these 2 (no matter what value of $t$), the series diverges? how certain are we and how do we prove that conclusively?

And dare I say i am a starting from CS background do i am totally lost how this straight forward calculation happens.. i mean i want to understand not just get an answer..

Note that $\tanh$ is a bounded function (on the real line that is). Hence, if $a\ge -1$ the integral diverges for $x \to \infty$ (This is also stated in the previous comments). Note that $x=0$ could lead to convergence problems.  The $\tanh$ function vanishes once at $x=0$. Therefore, locally around $x=0$ the integrand behaves like $x^{z+1}$. So the convergence question reduces to: when does $$\int_{0}^\epsilon x^{z+1} dx$$ converge? and that is exactly for $\Re (z+1) > -1$. Hence, $a>-2$. One has to verify that the integral converges for all $a \in (-2,-1)$, but this is now rather simple.

I have to admit that it would be hard to explain my answer in great detail, because I used many advanced concepts...

ah.. but if not imposing too much you can still write them.. i might be able to understand them eventually.. (and if any mistake at all, others might be able to point it out.. no offence :))

@stack.tarandeep You are right! I added a short overview for the calculation.  Now that I think about it maybe it is not so straight forward for somoene with less background...

Thanks a ton! I am accepting it (though i don't completely understand it :)) unless someone points out a mistake.
